# Speak At/Into Microphone

Tags: meaning, prepositions, idioms

For these two sentences:

> 1. He spoke ***at*** the microphone.
> 2. He spoke ***into*** the microphone.

, are they the same, or is one more poetic than the other?

Comment: Use "Speak into".

Answer (score 2):

1. The ordinary idiom is 'speak **into** the microphone'. Occasionally you will find a voice professional or sound engineer talk about 'speaking **across** the mic' (which is a technique for avoiding 'pop' or for dealing with an unusual mic setup) or encouraging an amateur to 'speak **to** the mic', meaning to speak as if the mic were a human listener. 'Speak **at** the mic' addresses the position at which the speaker stands.
2. In contemporary English 'poetic' is not usually a desirable stylistic quality. When ordinary people today speak of 'poetic' language what they usually have in mind is language marked by a high degree of sonic patterning, by conventional metaphor, and by a highly emotional tone. But English poetry itself abandoned the use of a distinctly 'poetic' diction more than a century ago, and this sort of language is now generally regarded as self-indulgent or meretricious. When sophisticated critics speak approvingly of 'poetic' qualities they are more likely to mean that a passage is intellectually and emotionally complex and suggests far more than it explicitly says.

Comment: To me, 'speak at the microphone' sounds like a public meeting. The guest speaker speaks, then the mc invites questions from the audience. One audience member has a loud voice and can be heard by everyone. Another has a soft voice and the mc invites him to come to the front and speak at the microphone.

Comment: @SydneyAustraliaESLTeacher A very good point I should not have overlooked.

Comment: Just like @SydneyAustraliaESLTeacher , I also feel that "speak at the microphone" sounds like a public meeting, and more specifically, sounds like "speak at the podium" where there might not be a podium, or the podium has a microphone.

Comment: I think native speakers can infer what speak *at* the microphone (might) mean, but it's not an expression we would actually use. *Go up to the mic/podium and speak,* or *Use the mic to speak,* or *Speak with a/the mic* might be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** This is **NOT** common. It sounds like it could mean either:
**a)** He spoke towards the microphone
**b)** He spoke being in the location of the microphone.

**2.** This **IS** common. This means:
He spoke projecting his voice towards the inside of the microphone(which is where sound is processed in the microphone).